# Integrate Backbone Boilerplate with jQuery Mobile and place layout structure

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I just started with Backbone.js, I've read the documentation and also the Backbone Fundamentals book before doing anything. I want to create a PhoneGap application with the help of Backbone.js and I'm a little bit lost on where to place some logic in Backbone.js or how integrate jQuery Mobile.

I need jQuery Mobile because I want to build an app with [this exact structure](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html), 2 panels that you can open with a swipe movement.

To integrate jQuery Mobile, the only thing that I've to do to BBB is to add a new Shim (and libs) in the [config file](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/config.js#L22)? Is that the correct workflow? Or should I touch something in `vendor/`?

Once I have the jQuery Mobile integrated to Backbone Boilerplate, I want to just reproduce the demo. I know how I will place this code in a old fashioned website, how I would place my files, etc. But when it comes to Backbone... I'm totally lost. Where is the place to put the JavaScript code that will start the functionality of the panels?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This guy's tutorial, although it's a year old, is a good starting point - http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, using jQueryMobile with Backbone gives headaches. Luckily I found a solution that simplifies the problem. It's a library called Jackbone. The author explained it better than I could do:

> Summary
>
> Jackbone is a utility library that aims to structure the development
>   of rich HTML5 applications using JQuery Mobile, by extending the
>   Backbone framework. It heavily relies on Backbone, offering
>   specialized classes for your views and router. Additionaly, it defines
>   a controller interface, provide a view manager that handles life and
>   death of the Views and Controllers of your application.

https://github.com/Fovea/jackbone